# Splitting header and content using regex

Tags: python, regex, split, fasta

I have the following sequence text in a file

every header starts with ">"
content number of lines is random

```
>XM_024446048.1 PREDICTED: Homo sapiens mannosidase alpha class 2A member 1 (MAN2A1), transcript variant X2, mRNA
CAGCCCCC
TGAGCGAC
TCCCTAATGTG
ACAGTAAAGAA
>NM_001308028.1 Homo sapiens FER tyrosine kinase (FER), transcript variant 2, mRNA
CAGCCC
CCGTGACGC
GGGGTGGTGACT
GGCTC
GGTGGT
GTGAC
>NM_0013082323028.1 H STZ mRSN1A
CAGCCC
CCGTGACGC
GGG
GTGGTGA
CTGGCTCCGGAGT
CTGAGGGGTTCGG
```

I want to create a nested dict in the following format:

```
nested_dict = { 'sequence1': {

'header': 'XM_024446048.1 PREDICTED: Homo sapiens mannosidase alpha class 2A member 1 (MAN2A1), transcript variant X2, mRNA',
'content': 'CAGCCCCCTGAGCGACTCCCTAATGTGACAGTAAAGAA'


},
               'sequence2': {

'header': 'NM_001308028.1 Homo sapiens FER tyrosine kinase (FER), transcript variant 2, mRNA',
'content': 'CAGCCCCCGTGACGCGGGGTGGTGACTGGCTCGGTGGTGTGAC'


},

               'sequence3': {

'header': 'NM_0013082323028.1 H STZ mRSN1A',
'content': 'CAGCCCCCGTGACGCGGGGTGGTGACTGGCTCCGGAGTCTGAGGGGTTCGG'


}
```

I'm stuck with regex expressions, can anyone help me?

Comment: why don't you first split on the ">" symbol (output.split(">")) and then use a more simple regex for the individual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^>
(?P<header>
[^\n()]*
    (?:\((?P<name>[^\n()]+)\))?
[^()\n]*
)
[\n\r]
(?P<content>[\s\S]+?)(?=^>|\Z)
```

with the `multiline` and `verbose` flag, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qxhty9/5/).

---

In `Python`:

```
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^>
    (?P<header>
    [^\n()]*
        (?:\((?P<name>[^\n()]+)\))?
    [^()\n]*
    )
    [\n\r]
    (?P<content>[\s\S]+?)(?=^>|\Z)''', re.M | re.X)

sequences = {"sequence{}".format(idx):
                 {"header": m.group('header'),
                  "content": m.group("content"),
                  "name": m.group('name')
                  }
             for idx, m in enumerate(rx.finditer(data), 1)}
print(sequences)
```

This yields

```
{'sequence1': {'header': 'XM_024446048.1 PREDICTED: Homo sapiens mannosidase alpha class 2A member 1 (MAN2A1), transcript variant X2, mRNA', 'content': 'CAGCCCCC\nTGAGCGAC\nTCCCTAATGTG\nACAGTAAAGAA\n', 'name': 'MAN2A1'}, 'sequence2': {'header': 'NM_001308028.1 Homo sapiens FER tyrosine kinase (FER), transcript variant 2, mRNA', 'content': 'CAGCCC\nCCGTGACGC\nGGGGTGGTGACT\nGGCTC\nGGTGGT\nGTGAC\n', 'name': 'FER'}, 'sequence3': {'header': 'NM_0013082323028.1 H STZ mRSN1A', 'content': 'CAGCCC\nCCGTGACGC\nGGG\nGTGGTGA\nCTGGCTCCGGAGT\nCTGAGGGGTTCGG', 'name': None}}
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/f2IwzO).

Comment: OMG! You're like a wizard of regex, thank you very much! Can i extract also the name between parentesis the same way you did? Something like: ```^>(?P<header>.+)(?P<name>\((.*?)\))[\n\r](?P<content>[\s\S]+?)(?=^>|\Z)```

Comment: What exactly is the Name?

Comment: i got it: ```^>(?P<header>.+[$\(](?P<name>.+)[$\)].+)[\n\r](?P<content>[\s\S]+?)(?=^>|\Z)``` it is the name between (). Thank you again <3

Comment: @LaraDiasVasconcelos: You could use a nested named capture group, see my updated example.